# write.csv in R is converting my dates into a 10 digit integer

Tags: r, csv, date, export-to-csv, date-conversion

In Excel, I created a Year End Date column of 1000 rows, where every cell's contents are 12/31/2018. I formatted this as a Date in Excel. I pulled this all into R, did some data manipulation on other columns, NOT the date column, and exported the final data frame out using write.csv. When I open the final file (in Excel or Tableau), my entire Year End Date column is coming out to be 1546214400 in every single cell.

Why is this happening? How can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at posixct function and origin argument.

Answer (score 5):

Every software program *stores* a date (or date time) as a number, but will *display* this number in a familiar date format for humans.

When you read your data into R, whatever function you used was "smart" enough to know that "12/31/2018" was the date "December 31, 2018" and not a string of characters "1, 2, /, 3, ..." all pasted together.  One way that R stores dates is as a POSIXct object.  We can see that R stored the date "12/31/2018" as the POSIXct integer 1546214400:

```
as.integer(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2018/12/31")))
> 1546214400
```

To export your data using `write.csv()` in a way such that the dates will be familiar to Excel, you first need to format the POSIXct value 1546214400 with a date format. So if your data are in a dataframe named `mydf` and the date column is named `date`, do this:

```
mydf$date <- format(mydf$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
write.csv(mydf, file="path/to/file.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in column types you can control column format.
\

```
coltypes <- cols( col1 = col_double(), col2 = col_double(), col3 = col_date(format ="%Y%m%d"), col4 = col_double())
```

then after you specify what each column should be, read the CSV in like this:
/

```
myData <- readr::read_csv("myCSV.csv", col_types = coltypes)
```